# php7.4 unable to read memcached data saved by pylibmc

Tags: php, memcached, python-3.8

I keep getting these errors trying to read memcached variables stored by python3 scripts runnnig pylibmc.

`PHP Warning:  Memcached::get(): could not decompress value: unrecognised compression type in xxx`

I'm saving some test data using this python3 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import pylibmc

mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True, 
     behaviors={"cas": True, "tcp_nodelay": True,"ketama": True})

mc.set('testvar', json.dumps('{"greeting": "Hello", "title": "Mr"}'), 3600)
```

Using telnet to fetch the variable from memcached shows the data is NOT compressed, but saved in clear text:

```
ubuntu@server:~/bin$ telnet localhost 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
get testvar
VALUE testvar 16 81
"{\"greeting\": \"Hello\", \"title\": \"Mr\"}"
END
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

I have set the compression limit in the php-memcached settings to a huge number:

/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini contains:

```
extension=memcached.so
; You need to install php-igbinary package to use igbinary serializer
; and php-msgpack to use msgpack serializer
memcached.serializer=php
memcached.compression_threshold=9999999999
```

The PHP script trying to read the data:

```
<?php
    echo ini_get("memcached.compression_threshold") . "\n";
    $mc = new Memcached();
    $mc->addServer('localhost', 11211);

    $data = json_decode($mc->get('testvar'));
    echo $data;
    echo "\n";

?>
```

and the output:

```
9999999999
PHP Warning:  Memcached::get(): could not decompress value: unrecognised compression type in /home/ubuntu/bin/memcache_get.php on line 6
```

This is on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20 LTS system with python 3.8.10 and pylibmc Version: 1.6.1

Any hints anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Saving to memcached from python as UTF-8 seems to work:

```
mc.set('testvar', json.dumps('{"greeting": "Hello", "title": "Mr"}').encode('UTF-8'), 3600)
```

makes it readable for php.